# Android : TextView with links Give NullPointerException onLongClick

Tags: android, textview

I can enable links via either:

A) in Code using

```
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
```

B) in XML

```
android:autoLink="all"    
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Whenever I enable links, a long click-listener fetches the tag of the View, which is a View-Holder. This View-holder object is returned as null whenever the Text-view has any links in it.

I have tried using both XML and Code approaches but it still is returning a null View-Holder object!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to give link to a textview and then implement longclick listener

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"your link here">Click here</a> "));
TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: the text is not pre-defined. i am making an sms application, so it is up to the user where any links appear!

any other ideas?

Comment: I think you're trying yo show a preview of the message. isn't? if so, get the message and the corresponding link, Then use the abouve method if links are present